# Filter Hibernate entities by the presence of a value in a many-to-many collection

Tags: java, hibernate, filter

I have a Hibernate entity (`A`) that contains a many-to-many collection of other entities (`B`).

I'm attempting to use Hibernate filters (using `@Filter` and `@FilterDef`) to only select those `A` entities whose collection contains a specific `B` entity.

Is this possible to achieve using filters?

(I may be misunderstanding the documentation - when setting a `@Filter` or `@FilterJoinTable` annotation to a collection, does this filter the collection or filter the resultset of the parent entity containing the collection?)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

`@Filter` works on target entity. Whereas `@FilterJoinTable` works on associated entity. Both are there to filter target entity. Suppose if there are no items in the associative collection on which `@FilterJoinTable` is set, then the target entity will not be returned, altogether.

Link to documentation, [Filtering data: Hibernate Filters](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#filters).

**Disclaimer:** I am not very experienced with `Hibernate Filters`. Its good to try it yourself.